# Sum over the rows using SQL but we need to stop and start the sum at specific condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

Here is an example of the data I have and the output I want in **SQL**.

| id | date | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-04-05 | 0 |
| a | 2022-04-06 | 1 |
| a | 2022-04-07 | 1 |
| a | 2022-04-08 | 1 |
| a | 2022-04-09 | 0 |
| a | 2022-04-10 | 0 |
| a | 2022-04-11 | 1 |
| a | 2022-04-12 | 1 |
| a | 2022-04-13 | 1 |
| a | 2022-04-14 | 1 |
| a | 2022-04-15 | 0 |
| a | 2022-04-16 | 0 |
| b | 2022-04-05 | 0 |
| b | 2022-04-06 | 1 |
| b | 2022-04-07 | 1 |
| b | 2022-04-08 | 0 |

**Desired Output**

| id | date | flag | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2022-04-05 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 2022-04-06 | 1 | 1 |
| a | 2022-04-07 | 1 | 2 |
| a | 2022-04-08 | 1 | 3 |
| a | 2022-04-09 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 2022-04-10 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 2022-04-11 | 1 | 1 |
| a | 2022-04-12 | 1 | 2 |
| a | 2022-04-13 | 1 | 3 |
| a | 2022-04-14 | 1 | 4 |
| a | 2022-04-15 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 2022-04-16 | 0 | 0 |
| b | 2022-04-05 | 0 | 0 |
| b | 2022-04-06 | 1 | 1 |
| b | 2022-04-07 | 1 | 2 |
| b | 2022-04-08 | 0 | 0 |

Basically the increment should start if the value of `flag` is 1 and continue incrementing until a `flag` of 0 is reached, then continue incrementing from the next `flag` of 1 until the next `0`, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  One approach uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, flag ORDER BY date) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, date, flag,
       SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY id, flag, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY date) AS count
FROM cte
ORDER BY id, date;
```